# Отношения между классами C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть в C# несколько связанных между собой форм. Как получить диаграмму классов всех форм я нашёл, но он просто выдаёт квадратики с методами и операндами из каждой формы, но без связей. Возможно ли в C# получить диаграмму сразу со связями между формами, или только самому их рисовать?

Comment: Есть [Code Map](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2019), но community его нет. Есть бесплатный [Quick Diagram](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FerencVizkeleti.QuickDiagramToolforC).

Comment: Установил этот  Quick Diagram, но он почему-то ничего не строит, просто запускается пустое окно.

Comment: Посмотрел Quick Diagram. Он работает, но только работает не так как вам нужно. Он не покажет связи классов по полям/методам. Есть еще `Code Graph`. Он тоже специфический(придется повозится с гуём) и даже глючный(может не правильно ссылки определять), но впринципе показывает ссылки.